# Poker dice probability of rolling 2 pairs

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Poker dice are played by rolling 5 dice. Let A be the event of rolling 2 pairs. (e.g. 1,1,2,2,3.). Find $\mathbb{P}(A)$.

So my answer is as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{1} \binom{1}{1}}{6^5}$$

Which yields to $\frac{25}{108}$ and it is indeed the correct answer.

However my classmate thought about this:

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{5}{1} \binom{3}{2} \cdot \binom{4}{1} \binom{1}{1}}{6^5}$$

which also makes sense to me, but it yields to a different answer, $\frac{25}{54}$, half of what the answer is supposed to be.

Why is the 2nd method wrong?

Comment: It is **twice** what it should be, because it double-counts the two pair hands. It counts for example two $1$'s, and two $5$'s, and a $4$, as different from two $5$'s, two $1$'s, and a $4$ as different hands.

Comment: You are welcome. This issue causes trouble, until one gets sensitized to it. In the second method, the $\binom{6}{1}$ implicitly counts the number of ways to the "first" of the two kinds we have a pair in, and the later $\binom{5}{1}$ picks the "second." However, there is no first or second. But multiple-counting can be useful! Sometimes we do it deliberately, afterwards dividing by a suitable factor to compensate.